# Are these two circuits equal and what does the arrow symbolize?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure what the arrow means, anyway V+ and V- were given as 5V and -5V respectively and Vin changes from -6V to 6V (so maybe an AC voltage source would've been appropriate).

Comment: I think the arrows on V+ and V- just mean that you connect them to the power supply terminals. Also, Vin should be within the boundaries of V+ and V-. The two sources in series should have a midpoint as you ground that will be a reference to your Vout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information provided, I think the circuits are correct. The arrows designate the currents through D1 and D2. For clarity you should also include a ground, most likely between the 2 5VDC power supplies. Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHsRy7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit: fixed negative terminal of V3 to be connected to ground per Naz' suggestion.

Comment: The V3 should be connected to GND, not to the negative rail?

Comment: There are many different reasons to add grounds in the real word.  Adding a ground here allows you to simplify your calculations.  It allows you to say "this node is zero" and go from there.  Unless you are going to implement this circuit in the real world, don't get too hung up on where the ground is placed.

Comment: @Naz yes, agreed and corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The arrows indicate when the diode conducts when the V_Anode > V_Cathode

The common Cathode resembles a Diode OR ( "high man wins" = conducts in direction of arrow)

Then the current to V- is defined by the voltage difference from the higher of the two: Vi:Vo minus V- over R2 ( minus the diode voltage drop)

A quick study defines the Vi for each diode to act as a switch and when Vi=Vo then you have a simple Vo/Vi=1 =R2/(R2+R1)

I leave Kirchoff's Laws for you to apply.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure what the arrow means

The arrows are likely used to indicate current. The "I" in "ID1" is usually short for current. And it usually shows up as a lower case "i". (Hence why electrical engineers use lower case "j" for complex numbers.) The direction is arbitrary. If the arrow is opposite of the actual current flow the value of the current is then said to be negative.

If you are adding the voltage sources according to the description of this problem, you are correct in that you need to use an source at Vi which changes from -6V to 6V over time.